# Modal pesquisa_pessoa não retorna nada quando muda pagina Javascript

Tags: javascript

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Bom dia

Estou usando um modal paginado com `datatable`, e quando pesquiso ou mudo de pagina a função para de adicionar na pagina principal a pessoa.

Função Javascript

```
$(function() {
    $('.add').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();


        var vId = $(this).parent().parent().find("#id").text();
        var vPessoa = $(this).parent().parent().find("#pessoa").text();

        //alert(vId + '/' + vPessoa)      

        $('#idforn01').attr('value', vId);
        $('#forn01').attr('value', vPessoa);
        // document.getElementById('forn01_teste').innerHTML = vPessoa;

    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quando você muda o DOM dessa forma que descreveu, o *javascript* "deixa de reconhecer" sua classe **.add** nos elementos "modificados", pois ele entende que é um novo elemento criado.

Você precisa delegar o seu click em uma elemento acima e informar o elemento a ser criado, ou seja, procure um elemento **PAI** que englobe sua lista do datatables e que ele nao seja modificado, e use ele.

Então, mude o seu código:

```
$('.add').click(function(e){ 
   e.preventDefault();
   ...
})
```

Para:

```
$([elemento_pai]).on('click', '.add', function(e){ 
   e.preventDefault();
   ...
})
```

Comment: Tacio, obrigado, porem deu esse erro Uncaught ReferenceError: elemento_pai is not defined

Comment: Esse [elemento_pai] você deve substituir por um elemento pai no seu código. Irei editar minha resposta para melhor compreensão

Comment: consegui pelo id do meu data table ficou assim <script type="text/javascript">
  $('#mytable01').on('click', '.add', function(e){ 
   e.preventDefault();
    var vId = $(this).parent().parent().find("#id").text();
    var vPessoa = $(this).parent().parent().find("#pessoa").text();

     alert(vId + '/' + vPessoa)  
});
</script>

Comment: Funcionou obrigado

Comment: Bacana, espero que tenha pegado a ideia. Estamos aqui pra ajudar!

Comment: Peguei sim Muito obrigado.

Comment: Não esquece de deixar como solucionado. Valeu!

Comment: Sem querer abusar, sou novo aqui como faço para deixar como solucionado?

Comment: No início da minha resposta, haverá um ícone parecido com um check de certo no canto esquerdo, basta clicar nele